# VB forms: Is there a way of having a constant comma in the middle of a text box that can't be edited

Tags: vb.net, text, textbox

I want to have a text box which allows you to enter the size of a grid, like the width and height. I want the text box to have a comma in the center so you can put the width on the left of it and the height on the right. (width,height)
How can I add this comma in and make it so it can't be changed by the user and acts as a divider between the values of the width and height.

Comment: Use two textboxes and a label between the two that shows a comma.

Comment: Have a look at the MaskedEdit control. You need to read the docs to get the hang of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `MaskedTextBox` rather than a `TextBox`, this will let you set an input mask for the required input, however you may need to fix the number of digits.